# how can I store more than ten thousands address in solidity array

Tags: solidity, contract-development, gas-price

i am trying to make lottery contract, and expected applicants will be about 2~30,000.

i want to set those applicants by this code.

```
function setApplicants(address[] memory _applicants) public onlyRole(DEFAULT_ADMIN_ROLE) {
        applicants = _applicants;
    }
```

but it seems i can't store thousands of addresses at once, even the limit of array size is 2^256-1 in solidity.

so i am wondering if there is a way to set applicants about 30,000. it doesn't have to be set at once. but i wish the used gas be minimum.

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You upload applicants in batches.

Each batch has a range like 0....1000, 1001...2000.

Also use a [Merkle tree](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/143040/620) instead of a naive array.

Comment: you mean push to array by 'for' statement?

Comment: merkle tree is a good thing, but i have to extract winners from applicants in contract. As far as I know, i can't extract values ​​from a Merkle tree. so i have to use naive array

Comment: well it seems this is the best for now. thanks